# ¿Cómo validar campos con AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Buenas tardes, les quiero preguntar porque no me realiza las validaciones que quiero en AngularJS.

**Html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
   <html ng-app="login"> 
      <head>    
        <title>Validar formularios</title>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>   
        <div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
            <br>
            <h2 align="center">{{message}}</h2>
            <br>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <form name="loginForm" novalidate> 
                   <label for="usr">Usuario: </label>
                   <input type="text" name="usuario" ng-model="usuario" required/>
                   <span ng-show="loginForm.usuario.$dirty && loginForm.usuario.$error.required">Error</span>
                   <br>
                   <label for="psw">Password: </label>
                   <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" required/>
                   <span ng-show="loginForm.password.$dirty && loginForm.password.$error.required">Error</span>
                   <br>
                   <input type="submit" value="ingresar" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid">
                </form>     
           </div>
       </div>

       <script src="js/app/loginApp.js"></script>
       <script src="js/controlador/loginCtrl.js"></script>
```

**AngularJS -- App**

```
var appLogin = angular.module('login', []);
```

**AngularJS -- Controller**

```
appLogin.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "Prueba de Login 10";
});
```

Tanto la App como el Controller andan, porque me muestra un mensaje que puse de prueba, Pero las validaciones no.

Copio validaciones que encuentro en internet y me andan, las copio yo tal cual y me generan problemas (me muestran error cuando no tienen o no muestran nada).

Muchas gracias

Matias

Comment: no estas cerrando la etiqueta <html> en tu codigo...

Comment: Si, pense que me habia olvidado cuando hice el copy & paste pero no lo tenia. Ahora funciona (estoy haciendo pruebas).
Gracias